# SonarQube settings appear to be empty on reload due to reverse proxy misconfiguration

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Originally it seemed that after a SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild analysis the server-side configured sonar.exclusions settings where cleared.

After some investigation it turned out that on page load of the Administration page an http 404.15 occured (in the SonarQube Web UI red alert is shown that a failed request occured which disappears quickly).

In our case we could solve the problem with adapting the configuration of the used IIS reverse proxy, specifically the request filtering module (if installed) has to allow a query string a larger than default. In our case 4096 seems to work.

Comment: `sonar.exclusions` on the server should be taken into account. Are you sure the exclusion pattern you used is correct? It might be tricky to get it right. The current answer is poking in the right direction.

Comment: The exclusion pattern worked, however after a run oft the MSBuild Runner the server-side setting is cleared, so on futher runs it isn't applied anymore.

Comment: Did you set `sonar.exclusions` on SonarQube web page, or some other way? (how exactly?)

Comment: I configured it on the _Analysis Scope_ tab in the project _Administration_ view.

Comment: And do you confirm that after running MSBuild Runner, the configuration on SonarQube is removed? That would be extremely surprising. Can you please double-check?

Comment: You're right, it only appeared to be cleared out after the MSBuild Runner analysis. In fact the configuration was still there but the browser wasn't able to load it do to a blocked request to _https://sonar/api/settings/values?keys=sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria..._

I've tried to increase the query string length (as the error was a HTTP 404.15) to 4096 bytes (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits/) with _<requestLimits maxQueryString="4096" />_

Comment: So it seems you are seeing a failing request due to extremely long URL. But it's not clear where you see this, what exactly it is, and what events lead to this effect. Can you please edit the question and explain all the detailed steps needed to reproduce the problem. Right now it's not very clear what is happening, where, and how.

Comment: Done, is it clear enough?

Comment: If increasing the `maxQueryString` setting solved your problem, you could post that as an answer. On the other hand, I don't understand what could cause such a long request, and that doesn't sound normal. It could be interesting to debug that, if posted as a new question, with enough details to reproduce it.

Comment: As mentioned above, all I did was to open the analysis scope page in the project administration. During the page load a request to /api/settings/values is performed with a very long query string which is longer than 2048 bytes.

It seems that with each installed plugin additional parameters are requested on this page and therefore a request longer than 2048 bytes is possible.

Answer (score 2):

I think how to exclude with MSBuild depends on what you are trying to exclude.  I was only able to exclude an entire project by using the property group in the csproj.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Exclude this project from analysis -->
    <SonarQubeExclude>true</SonarQubeExclude>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

However I was able to successfully exclude files and groups of files with the sonar.exclusions settings through the SonarQube UI (project administration, analysis scope, files).  The pattern that I could get to work was **/folder1/folder2/file where folder1 is the first folder inside your project root (not solution root).  Adding what you are trying to exclude would help me be more specific on my answer.